# Marking message as spam or important

Tags: imapclient

I have a Django email client powered by [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. I successfully control read/unread status, as well as deleted. As descriped [here](http://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#message-flags).

My code for declaring a message as readlooks like this:

```
from imapclient.imapclient import SEEN
server.add_flags(msg_uids, SEEN)
```

Now I am stuck trying to add flag `'Junk'` to the message.
I mean, doing something like:

```
server.add_flags(msg_uids, '\Junk')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here. Firstly, flags that start with "" are system flags and `\Junk` isn't a standard system flag (as defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.2)).

Are you sure the server you're talking to supports the `\Junk` flag? You can check what flags the server lets the client set by checking for a `PERMANENTFLAGS` response in the return from IMAPClient's `select_folder()` call. This lists the flags the client is allowed to change. Is `\Junk` included?

If `PERMANENTFLAGS` includes `\*` then the client is allowed to define new keywords (flags that don't start with `\`) just by using them. See [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-64) for further details. If `\*` isn't included then the client may only set the listed flags.